# What is the best way to store JSON response of third API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, architecture, software-design

I'm using a third API where I have the concept of Orders and Offers, and I want save some things from the response of creation endpoint for both resources and I want save entire response if someday I need a particular thing from the response that I not consider yet.

What is the best pattern to follow in this cases? (pattern in Database and in Application [Rails follow MVC model])

Comment: What have you considered? What have you tried? What has worked? What hasn't worked? How do you define "best" as in "best pattern"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most case I encounter, we won't needs to query the full raw response, so mostly we use `ActiveRecord/Store` to store our full response, this gives you a easy way to get particular information in case you need it in the future, but at the same time, won't take too much space from your db.

you can find great example in official doc, so I won't repeat it here.
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html

Answer (score 1):

Activerecords do support JSON,
You can save the whole JSON response into your DB

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json-and-jsonb